# Is there an alternative for injectBoundHTML in 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Before Polymer 0.8 we were able to stamp databound HTML in the DOM using `injectBoundHTML`. In 1.0 this function no longer exists. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can set the `innerHTML` of your custom elements just like you would do to other elements.

```
Polymer({

  is: 'x-custom',

  ready: function() {
    this.innerHTML = 'Hello World, I am a <b>Custom Element!</b>';
  }

});
```

I am not sure if the Polymer team has implemented a special method like `injectBoundHTML` to do this.

Comment: Adi, thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to append HTML that includes binding annotations, like for example: `<span>{{helloMessage}}</span>`. That's what the injectBoundHTML did before 0.8.